# Parametric form in R^3

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the statement in red, i.e.
$$this <=> that$$
correct?

[image]

I'm pretty sure it is, and we have $s=-t$.

In general, if the point (a,b,c) is on the plane, then d(a,b,c) is also on the plane, for some scalar d?

Comment: $(0,2,6)$ is on the black line but not on the red one.

Comment: I am the one who calculated the black, and the book's answer is the red. Am I or the book correct?

Comment: Yours is closest, yet both are wrong, as can be easily checked by substitution...BTW, bad idea to use "s" when there are so many $\;5$'s close to it and both get confused.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Choosing $\;t=-5\;$ in the left side, you have that we get

$$\begin{pmatrix}\!\!\!-5\\37\\31\end{pmatrix}$$

and in order to get that in the right side you'd have to choose $\;s=5\;$ for the first coordinate, yet the other ones are wrong...